# jenkins : no disk space available

Tags: jenkins

I am executing a job in Jenkins and in between it throws error and failed with following error :

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
   [testng]     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
   [testng]     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:163)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeUtf8File(Utils.java:115)
```

DEBUG :
But there are lots of spaces available in disk. I tried df -h to get the below information. My Jenkins folder and tmp are in /dev/mapper/centos-root which has 500GB disk

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on<br>
/dev/mapper/centos-root          500G   91G  410G  19% /<br>
devtmpfs                          12G     0   12G   0% /dev<br>
tmpfs                             12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm<br>
tmpfs                             12G   17M   12G   1% /run<br>
tmpfs                             12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup<br>
/dev/sda1                        497M  106M  392M  22% /boot<br>
/dev/mapper/centos-home           28G  1.5G   27G   6% /home<br>
```

Not able to understand why Jenkins throws such error when disk space is there? Is there any job specific limit set in Jenkins ?

Comment: pls also post what your inode and memory usage is: `df -i` and `free -m`. you should also run these during the job.

Comment: df -i:Filesystem                         Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root         524283904   153230 524130674    1% /
devtmpfs                          3062615      406   3062209    1% /dev
tmpfs                             3064789        1   3064788    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             3064789      475   3064314    1% /run
tmpfs                             3064789       13   3064776    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                          512000      330    511670    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home          28827648        6  28827642    1% /home

Comment: free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         23943      20920       3023          7          0      15965
-/+ buffers/cache:       4954      18988
Swap:         2063         82       1981

Comment: how i run these continueously. Is it like running the script separately every 1 min ?

Comment: I don't see any issues there if I am reading the unformatted output correctly. To run this in the job, add it as a shell step. Look for maxing of the inode usage in case that's the issue. Too many variables to say definitively but that will give clues.

Comment: sure, will try that out.

Comment: one last diagnostic is the `ulimit -n` which tells you the number of open file descriptors. the limits are set in http://ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html